# Asus Laptop poor battery life

Tags: xubuntu, asus, battery

I recently bought an Asus r556l Laptop which comes with a 37.3Wh / 7.5v battery, which is advertised to last 5 hours, but when using xubuntu 16.04, I notice that only lasts for 3 hours max. Also, I notice something weird which is that when it's connected to the AC adapter, and after reaching 99%, it keeps being charged instead of stopping and staying at 100%, so I don't know if this is related.

Maybe this is normal, but I am asking because at work, I use an Acer laptop with a 48.9Wh / 17.1v battery, and according to this website: https://milliamps-watts.appspot.com/ that should mean that that laptop's battery has 2859mAh whereas mine has 4973mAh, and the Acer laptop stays between 5-5.5 hours on whereas mine only 3 hours with usage being writing code and so not gaming or anything power-intensive (and both running xubuntu 16.04), so I assume that my laptop should stay on much longer.

Is my laptop's battery broken? Should ask for a replacement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have read that power management is not something the Linux Kernel is very good at (but they are working on to improve it).

That being said, a drop from 5.5 hours to 3 hours is, I would say, "normal".

Take for example. My laptop can run for 2 hours on Windows (pathetic, I know), but when I switched to Ubuntu, the battery lasts for barely 1 hour.

Comment: Also notice that the "advertised"  value is calculated with basic to little load,  if you're running, daemons, servers or any other heavy processes, you will see a significant decrease on that value.

Comment: Yes - forgot to mention that too. Thanks @bistoco

Comment: I've heard before about the issues with power management on Linux, but what I'm saying is that I am running Linux on two laptops (so both should have the same power management issues) but still one of them runs for longer even though it's battery has less capacity, which makes me wonder why that's happening. I am not comparing one laptop running Windows and the other running Linux...